# React JS Crud Issues with mutable data

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, react-router, crud

All im trying to do is simple pull of data from an API then list the data and have a react route function to change the form fields to the relevant listing you are changing.

So far I am able to do all that except mutate the data because every time I do that it says state is not defined.

the component is below that is passed props to change the input values to the relevant listing when edit is clicked.

And please do not link me to the form documentation on react I have read it 50 times lol.

error message I have when im trying to mutate the data 
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined

```
export default class List extends Component {

    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            announcements: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

        const fetchValues = {
            mode: 'cors',
            method: 'GET',
            credentials: 'include',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }

        fetch('https://api.lonres.pde/workflow/announcement', fetchValues).then((response)=> {
            return response.json();
        }).then((response) => {
            this.setState({announcements: response})
        })

    }

    render() {
        const announcements = this.state.announcements;
        return (
            <Router>
                <section>
                    <ul>
                        {announcements.map(data => {
                            return <li onClick={ () => {}} key={data.announcement_id} className={data.is_active}>
                                <p>{data.announcement_id}</p>
                                <p>{data.description}</p>
                                <Link to={`/workflow_announcement/edit/${data.announcement_id}`}>
                                    <div>Edit</div>
                                </Link>
                            </li>
                        })}
                    </ul>
                    {announcements && (
                        <Route path='/workflow_announcement/edit/:announcementID' render={({ match }) => (
                            <Edit data={announcements.find(a => a.announcement_id == match.params.announcementID)}/>
                        )}/>
                    )}
                </section>
            </Router>
        );

    }
}



export default class Edit extends Component {

    /**
     * @constructor
     */

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: props.data
        };
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({data: event.target.value});
    }


    render() {
        const valid = function( current ){
            return current.day() !== 0 && current.day() !== 6;
        };
        console.log(this.state.data)
        return (
            <form>
                <div className="announcements">
                    <h4>{this.props.data.announcement_id}</h4>
                    <textarea cols="50" rows="5" value={this.props.data.description} onChange={this.handleChange}></textarea>
                    <section>
                        <h5>To:</h5>
                        <Datetime
                            value={this.props.data.start_datetime}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            dateFormat="YYYY-MM-D"
                            timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
                            isValidDate={ valid }
                        />
                        <h5>From:</h5>
                        <Datetime
                            value={this.props.data.end_datetime}
                            onChange={this.handleChange}
                            dateFormat="YYYY-MM-D"
                            timeFormat="HH:mm:ss"
                            isValidDate={ valid }
                        />
                    </section>
                    <input type="checkbox" checked={this.props.data.is_active} onChange={this.handleChange}  />
                    <button>ok</button>
                </div>
            </form>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {value: ''};

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      }

handleChange(event) {
        this.setState({value: event.target.value});
      }
```

You need to `bind(this)`  to make it work in the callback

There is another way to handle with that,you can check the document of reactjs.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/handling-events.html